# Cocoa application menu - how to recreate?

Tags: cocoa, macos, nsmenu

Inside the MainMenu.xib I deleted the default Main Menu that automatically gives you the application menu (along with the File/Edit/Format/View/Window/Help menus).

What are the steps I need to take to add this back into my application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would create a new application then copy just the `Main Menu` back into your `MainMenu.xib`

Comment: Thanks, this worked.  I'd still like to understand the 'magic' that relates this Menu to the application as it's main menu.

Comment: @zadam: There's no magic. It's just a complete main menu that Apple created for you and supplied in the nib in each application template. That menu is the main menu because the application's `mainMenu` outlet is hooked up to it.

Comment: - Peter: where is the application's mainMenu outlet hooked up to it?

Comment: @zadam: In the MainMenu nib, where the main menu resides and the application is the File's Owner. Right-click on the main menu and you should see the application's `mainMenu` as a referencing outlet.

Comment: @PeterHosey I expected this to be the case, but no "mainMenu" outlet appears in Interface Builder for either File's Owner or the Application instance. Only delegate and dockMenu appear.

Comment: @MikeyWard: Correct. The `mainMenu` outlet is no longer exposed in Xcode's nib editor. Only the older separate Interface Builder shows it. WrightsCS's solution is now the only way.

Comment: That's a bummer. It's disappointing from a philosophical perspective that one can't have a nibless project.