# Re-create Cocoa application menubar

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, interface-builder, menubar

I'm making a statusbar application and load a new xib containing the main window for the application when clicking on a statusbar menu item. However, in the process I deleted the application menu bar. I don't see a way to hook up the NSMenu object I created in the interface builder.

The window loads just fine, and the status bar icon is still present, but when I make the main window the key window, the application menu bar doesn't change, it just shows the previous app that was active.

I have followed the instructions/suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300256/cocoa-application-menu-how-to-recreate) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734213/how-do-i-add-main-menu-to-xib), but neither of them work. Is there some other step I've missed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you're describing is normal for background applications. If you don't have an icon in the Dock, you don't get your own menubar, even if you have a window in the foreground.

Comment: Gotcha. That was probably mentioned in the Apple Docs somewhere, but I didn't notice. Thanks!

Comment: I am on this problems too. Thanks Joseph Quigley.